# Aurelia Validation - What is the best way to access validation error on specific property?

Tags: validation, properties, message, aurelia

I have a custom text-field component which encapsulates mdl textfield. I am passing desired value through its bindable property. I want to declare (and validate) validation rules in common view model and then pass possible validation error to each text-field (Which should display it however it wants).

my current pseudocode:

```
<template>
    <text-field 
        value.two-way="entity.value1">
    </text-field>
    <text-field 
        value.two-way="entity.value2">
    </text-field>
</template>
```

How can I pass validation error for value1 into first textfield and validation error for value2 into second?

The best i was able to do was:

```
<template>
    <div validation-errors.bind="firstValidationErrors">
        <text-field 
            value.two-way="entity.value1"
            errors.bind="firstValidationErrors">
        </text-field>
    <div>
    <div validation-errors.bind="secondValidationErrors">
        <text-field 
            value.two-way="entity.value2"
            errors.bind="secondValidationErrors">
        </text-field>
    <div>
</template>
```

But I have to create each validation errors array in viewmodel (I am not sure if I really have to but linting forces me to). And also I have to wrap every control in my page. Is there a better way?

Can I do something like this?

```
<template>
    <text-field 
        value.two-way="entity.value1"
        validation-errors.bind="firstValidationErrors"
        errors.bind="firstValidationErrors">
    </text-field>

    <text-field 
        value.two-way="entity.value2"
        validation-errors.bind="secondValidationErrors"
        errors.bind="secondValidationErrors">
    </text-field>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want your `text-field` to have full control over displaying the errors, why not just make that into a [validation renderer](http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#custom-renderers)?

It's quite straightforward:

1. Inject `ValidationController` and `Element` into your custom element via the constructor
2. On `bind()` you register it like so: `this.controller.addRenderer(this);`
3. On `unbind()` you unregister it like so: `this.controller.removeRenderer(this);`
4. Implement the `render` method like so:

   ```
   public render(instruction: RenderInstruction) {
     for (const { result } of instruction.unrender) {
       const index = this.errors.findIndex(x => x.error === result);
       if (index !== -1) {
         this.errors.splice(index, 1);
       }
     }

     for (const { result, elements } of instruction.render) {
       if (result.valid) {
         continue;
       }
       const targets = elements.filter(e => this.element.contains(e));
       if (targets.length) {
         this.errors.push({ error: result, targets });
       }
     }
   }
   ```

That gives you the errors in your custom element. You might as well just directly do the rendering there though.

Note that this example I'm giving you is pretty much a copy-paste from the `validation-errors` custom attribute [source](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/validation-errors-custom-attribute.ts)